# Fix comparison data from text

Tags: python

I have written a program (mostly copy/paste) to compare vehicle A price  (`v_priceA`) to various other vehicle prices in a `carprices.txt` text file which are in a new line.

The result should be a new text called `highprices.txt` file with all the prices greater than the price of Vehicle A in a newline.

My problem is the resultant text file has the line number of the greater file, instead of the greater price itself. I need to fix this.

Vehicle A price: 2500.50

carPrices.txt

```
2500.40
2900.00
3500.50
2200.00
25000.30
45000.50
```

highprices.txt

```
2900.00
3500.50
25000.30
45000.50
```

```
import numpy as np
v_priceA = 2500.50
a_file = 'carprices.txt'
with open(a_file, 'r') as document:
    values = [x for x, value in enumerate(document) if float(value) > v_priceA] 

new_file = open('highprice.txt', 'w')
for x in values:
    new_file.write(str(x) + '\n')`
```

My result:
highprice.txt

```
2
3
5
6
```

Desired result:

highprices.txt

```
2900.00
3500.50
25000.30
45000.50
```

Comment: You are saving to values the index (x). You should do         values = [float(value) for x, value in enumerate(document) if float(value) > v_priceA]

Comment: @lara_g1999, I added an answer to your question.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Thank you your answer works. I have a question. What does x for x mean ?

Comment: @nacho Thank you.

Comment: @lara_g1999, this is part of Python syntax, and it is very similar from a mathematical way to define a set. Let's assume `l` is a list, `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, so `[x for x in l]` means that for every element `x` (you can name it whatever you want) in the list `l`, you are going to do something in this case you just get the same value. You can also do `[2 * x for x in l]` and you will get `[2, 4, 6, 8]`. This is a [list comprehension](https://medium.com/better-programming/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading a file, you can take advantage of of using a loop and it will give you each line of the file, so this will fix your problem:

```
values = [value for value in document if float(value) > v_priceA]
```

The previous line is a feature of Python called list comprehension, it is equivalent to the following code:

```
values = []

for value in document:
    if float(value) > v_priceA:
        values.append(value)
```

If you want to use the values from the file, you should cast those values before appending them to the list, but because I see you store those values and just save them in another file, you can avoid converting them to float before appending them to `values`.

The final version of your code, to produce the desired result, will be:

```
v_priceA = 2500.50
a_file = 'carprices.txt'
with open(a_file, 'r') as document:
    values = [value for value in document if float(value) > v_priceA] 

with open('highprice.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in values:
        f.write(str(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v_priceA = 2500.50
a_file = 'carprices.txt'
with open(a_file, 'r') as document:
    values = [value for value in document if float(value) > v_priceA] 

new_file = open('highprice.txt', 'w')
for x in values:
    new_file.write(str(x) + '\n')`
```

Variable in assignment, uses `x` instead of `value`. Is `enumerate` required?

Comment: I actually don't know what the enumerate is for. I'm still learning and I had found that code on here somewhere.